# highlight a label which goes before a checkbox if checkbox is checked

Tags: html, css, checkbox, highlight, checked

I have a problem to highlight a label which goes before a checkbox (Case #1). I use this code, but for some reason, the highliting is not working here:

```
Case #1

HTML
<label class="mylabel">My Label</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="mycheck" />

CSS
.mylabel + .mycheck:checked {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

At the same, if a label goes after a checkbox (Case #2) then the label is highlighted successfully:

```
Case #2

HTML
<input type="checkbox" class="mycheck" />
<label class="mylabel">My Label</label>


CSS
.mycheck:checked + .mylabel {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I am interested only in a non-javascript way of highlighting a label which goes before a checkbox. What is wrong with the Case #1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `+` selector selects the next element (in other words + is scanning the element's siblings in HTML which are declared later than current one and gets the first match) and in fact you assign `font-weight: bold;` on a checkbox which is funny but not what you expect. CSS doesn't have a *previous* selector (in other words there is no selector to scan the element's siblings in HTML which are declared before current one), so the thing you ask is not really achievable.

The only way is to **display** the element before the checkbox, e.g. assigning `float: left` to the label and `float: right` to the checkbox. But still, the order of the elements in HTML must be the following:

1. checkbox
2. label

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It helps me.